# Continue with Loop even if Excel not have tab

Tags: r, for-loop, import, error-handling

I am new to R and trying to write some code that will loop over all the files in my a folder, and then pull in all the data associated with a certain tab.  However, this tab may not be present in all of the files I have stored in this folder.  To trouble shoot this, I am using a Try-Catch function, but am still running into issues.

What else do I need to do so I just loop over the data if the tab is not present, and not load it in?

This is what I have tried:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(filesinfolderfull_list)){
  print(filesinfolder_list[i])
  i_ddolv_temp <- tryCatch (
    { read_excel(filesinfolderfull_list$datafiles[i], sheet="Display-OLV Reporting",col_names=TRUE,skip=4)},
error = function(e){print("skip")}
  )
  templateDDOLV_df<- bind_rows(templateDDOLV_df,i_ddolv_temp)  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get from your explanation that some excels do not have the `"Display-OLV Reporting"` sheet. Why not look up first with `excel_sheets` and then extract if `TRUE`. Something like:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(filesinfolderfull_list)){
  print(filesinfolder_list[i])
  if ("Display-OLV Reporting"%in%excel_sheets(read_excel(filesinfolderfull_list$datafiles[i]){
      i_ddolv_temp <- read_excel(filesinfolderfull_list$datafiles[i], sheet="Display-OLV Reporting",col_names=TRUE,skip=4)
      templateDDOLV_df<- bind_rows(templateDDOLV_df,i_ddolv_temp) 
   } 
}
```

You could use a variable to not read each excel twice

Comment: AhH! Thanks! That fixed my problem.

Comment: no problem, if this solves your question mark it as an accepted answer to close the question.